# Is it possible to share Amazon AMI images to other users programatically using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Is it possible to share an AMI using AWS SDK? I know I can share AMI images using AWS console or CLI as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html .
I searched through the AWS documentation but I have not been able to find any documentation/examples that let you share AMIs using AWS SDK. Is it possible at all?

EDIT: Also, is it possible to share AMI images to other IAM users?

Answer (score 1):

That's right to modify and attribute on an AMI (or Amazon Image) you want to follow the link that you provided. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-ModifyImageAttribute.html)

The AMI section of EC2 only allows you to create minimal permissions. One is the permissions given an AWS account Id which is usually something like: `123456789012`. Keep in mind that an account Id is associated to the main or primary user of the AWS account (for example your email address).  The other type of permission it allows you to do is group permissions but it looks like Amazon hasn't gotten around implementing it yet since the only value allow for Group is `all`.

AIM provides you more granular permission access for users that are below in hierarchy from main account id (or the main email address).

Now to use AIM to give permissions to Amazon Images (AMIs) you need to associate an AIM policy to a user or group that has AMI permissions. For example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1388772918000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateImage",
        "ec2:DeregisterImage"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:image/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This policy gives permissions to create and deregister and image on all the instances and images under `us-east-1` for account id `123456789012`.

You can do all of the above programmatically too.

[Edit]

This is the list of possible EC2 ARN values from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-ec2 :

```
arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/instance-id
arn:aws:iam::account:instance-profile/instance-profile-name
arn:aws:ec2:region:account:placement-group/placement-group-name
arn:aws:ec2:region::snapshot/snapshot-id
arn:aws:ec2:region:account:volume/volume-id
```

Comment: Thank you Rico for your answer.
I have added a policy for the two actions that you mentioned for a particular group, but I couldn't create a new AMI with that. Do I also need to provide "RegisterImage" action in the action list?

Also, I was wondering, where did you get the resource names from?
I didn't find "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:[awsid]:instance/*" in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html.

Comment: It seems that even adding "RegisterImage" in the action list does not enable the users under that group to create new AMIs.

Comment: I would try added all the Image actions in this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-apis.html and then start removing the ones that you don't need. Make sure you can have permissions adding all the "image" actions to your policy. Here you can find all the AIM EC2 resource types (for arns) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: I tried to add all the Image actions but still I am not able to create AMI. I get following error " AWS Error Code: UnauthorizedOperation, AWS Error Message: You are not authorized to perform this operation."
I also tried to give all permissions of ec2 like       
"Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:image/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*"
      ].
That too didn't work. Do I need to add resources other than image and instance? Can I find these in documentation?

Comment: Try `arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:volume/*` to allow all the volumes. There's might be other resources as well. Also are you using `us-east-1`  or a different region?

Comment: Yes, I am also using us-east-1 region. I tried "...:volume/*" as well. It seems that I need other resources as well. Do you have any idea where I can find the permissions required in the AWS SDK documentation?

Comment: Check the [Edit] above.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. For example look at the boto.ec2.image class. (The python sdk)

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.image

I'm  sure the ruby, js and java SDKs can do it too as they all use the AWS API.

As a matter of fact the cli also uses the API.

Also here's for example the EC2 API reference on how to create an image.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CreateImage.html

And yes you can share AMIs with other users depending on the AIM policies on the users.

Comment: Thank you Rico for your answer. I have not been able to share AMI images using the java SDK. The link that you provided takes me to CreateImage documentation, but I need to be able to share an already existing AMI image.
I went through the documentation and found ModifyImageAttribute at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-ModifyImageAttribute.html.
However, I want to share it with IAM users and groups. I am not able to figure out AWS userid for a IAM user or group.